# Loop in js.erb file iterates twice as often than it should

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

There is an array in one of my rails controllers. I would like to loop through its elements in the corresponding js.erb file. The problem is that it seems to iterate two times for each element. Here is the code:

```
<% @array.each do |element| %>
    table_row = document.getElementById("<%= element[:row_id]%>")
    if (table_row != null)
    {
        <% p "row found:" %>
        <% p element[:row_id] %>
    }
    else
    {
        <% p "row not found:" %>
        <% p element[:row_id] %>
    }
<% end %>
```

Lets say `@array` has 3 elements. Then the code above would generate a very strange output:

```
row found:
1
row not found:
1
row found:
2
row not found:
2
row found:
3
row not found:
3
```

My first question is: Why are there 6 iterations when `@array` has 3 elements?
Second question: Why does the result of `getElementById` alternate between null and (not null)?

Comment: I think There is an issue in code,
How will you assign a javascript variable to ruby?
`table_row = document.getElementById("<%= element[:row_id]%>")`

Comment: Ruby executes on server, javascript on the client. They don't know about each other. You're assuming they execute at the same time; they do not. A template file generates JS, which is executed later. It prints exactly what you'd expect; the Ruby code doesn't care about the JS conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most probably that the internal code is ruby, which is executed regardless of the `if` condition in the js code. By using `p` you tell ruby to print those lines to the server console, because the js will be executed only on client side, there is no chance to put anything to the server console.

Basically you do two things: first you generate a js containing some condition with empty blocks, and second during that you print some lines to the rails server console. You cant mix the things like that. Use something like this, to see:

```
<% @array.each do |element| %>
    table_row = document.getElementById("<%= element[:row_id]%>")
    if (table_row != null)
    {
        alert("row found: <%= element[:row_id] %>");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("row not found: <%= element[:row_id] %>");
    }
<% end %>
```